# AWK condition handling

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text data as

```
A 00 
B 05 
C d1 
D
```

I want to read the above text file and trigger a shell script `abc.sh` when `$2` is either `"05"` `" "` or  `"d1"`. Using Awk, how can this be done?

I tried

```
$ awk '{ if ($2 ==" " && $2 == "05" && $2 == "d1") run abc.sh else print "HELLO" }' –
```

Comment: `$2` can't be a space if you're using whitespace as the delimiter.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run the script for every line which matches one of your conditions, or run it once if one of the lines matches the condition? Awk doesn't know what `run abc.sh` means; you are probably looking for `system()`, though perhaps it's better to refactor to not do that part from Awk, depending on what exactly you mean.

Comment: `&&` means "and"; the condition cannot be true. You probably mean "or": `NF==1 || $2 == "05" || $2 == "d1"` though that can be simplified to `NF==1 || $2 ~ /^(05|d1)$/`

Comment: Why not add a `BEGIN { ... }` rule and create an array holding the field-values for $2 that will prompt running of the script, e.g. `runscript["05"] = 1; runscript[""]=1`. Then you can just check if `$2 in runscript` to determine whether to call the script.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But How can i run a shell script inside awk condition?? Is it possible?

Comment: You can use the `system()` function to call shell commands, see [Using bash shell function inside AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72935/using-bash-shell-function-inside-awk)

Answer (score 2):

This AWK code

```
{ if ($2 ==" " && $2 == "05" && $2 == "d1") run abc.sh else print "HELLO" }
```

has numerous issues

- as default field separator is one or more whitespace characters, there will be never field which is single space character, for file as shown you might use `$2==""` to detect line with missing 2nd field
- `&&` is logical AND, so your condition does never holds as if 2nd field is `05` then it is *not* `d1` and vice versa, you should use `||` which is logical OR if you want to say 2nd field is either `05` or `d1`
- you are missing `;` before `else`, if you want to cram if thenbody else elsebody on one line either use `;` before else or enclosed bodies in curled braces, consult [If Statement (The GNU Awk Users Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/If-Statement.html) for details
- `run` is neither GNU AWK built-in function or variable, use [`system`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) function if you wish to run shell command
- you are referencing `abc.sh` like *variable* but that is not legal variable name

After repairing that issues, code might become

```
{ if ($2 =="" || $2 == "05" || $2 == "d1"){system("bash abc.sh")}else{print "HELLO"}}
```

Then for `file.txt` content

```
A 00 
B 05 
C d1 
D
```

and `abc.sh` content

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'I am abc.sh'
```

command

```
awk '{ if ($2 =="" || $2 == "05" || $2 == "d1"){system("bash abc.sh")}else{print "HELLO"}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
HELLO
I am abc.sh
I am abc.sh
I am abc.sh
```

Observe that I assumed `abc.sh` is supposed to be used as follows `bash abc.sh` if this is not case feel free to change 1st argument of `system` function call.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
 awk '$2~"05|d1"||NF==1{system("./abc.sh")}' input.txt
```